# Check backpressure live on Exchange2010 server

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010, windows-event-log

I am working a lot with exchange servers at the moment and would like to make sure there is no backpressure built up on them. Right know I have a powershell script running every 4h to check the eventlog:

```
$username = "Administrator"
$password = cat C:\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred     = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
$server   = "hubextserver"
$body     = @()

#Event ID 15004: Increase in the utilization level for any resource (eg from Normal to Medium)
$15004    = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName Application -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | where {$_.EventID -eq "15004"}
if ($15004) {$time04  = $15004.TimeGenerated.ToString()
$message04 = $15004.Message.ToString()
$body = $body + $time04
$body = $body + $message04}
#Event ID 15005: Decrease in the utilization level for any resource (eg from High to Medium)
$15005    = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName Application -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | where {$_.EventID -eq "15005"}
if ($15005) {$time05  = $15005.TimeGenerated.ToString()
$message05 = $15005.Message.ToString()
$body = $body + $time05
$body = $body + $message05}
#Event ID 15006: High utilization for disk space (ie critically low free disk space)
$15006    = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName Application -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | where {$_.EventID -eq "15006"}
if ($15006) {$time06  = $15006.TimeGenerated.ToString()
$message06 = $15006.Message.ToString()
$body = $body + $time06
$body = $body + $message06}
#Event ID 15007: High utilization for memory (ie critically low available memory)
$15007    = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName Application -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | where {$_.EventID -eq "15007"}
if ($15007) {$time07  = $15007.TimeGenerated.ToString()
$message07 = $15007.Message.ToString()
$body = $body + $time07
$body = $body + $message07}
$noerror  = "No errors!"

if ($body)  {
Send-MailMessage -To Recipient -Subject "Backpressureerror at $server" -body "$body" -SmtpServer smtpserver -Credential $cred -from sender} 
  else  {
Send-MailMessage -To Recipient -Subject "Backpressure Test at $server - No errors" -body "$noerror" -SmtpServer smtpserver -Credential $cred -from sender}
```

However, my goal would be to have a way to get informed right away, or within a few minutes if backpressure is built up. Eventlog doesn't seem to be the most efficient way. Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows Performance Monitor provides live performance data, and there are many counters for Exchange. SCOM (system center operations manager) is the product MS sells for enterprise monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

We use the PRTG monitoring application (100 sensors free if you want to try it) and we get SMS notifications if our customised limits are reached, we also plot live graphs of certain key statistics on a screen for our Core Team technicians to constantly check with large green - orange - red blocks for warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a real-time event log monitoring solution, there are a plethora of options available on the market today, including many free and open source options.

If you are looking for something free and easy to install, I'd recommend the free edition of our monitoring product EventSentry, "EventSentry Light". It's developed for Windows, monitors event logs in real time, there is no registration for download, and the setup is fast and pain-free. It also doesn't have any .NET etc. system requirements.

You can take a look and download at http://www.eventsentry.com.